# Sampling extremely large and diverse dataset?

Tags: sampling, random-variable, random-generation, finance

General theories would be great. My specific problem is I'm trying to find a specific portfolio of all the stocks in the market. The possibilities are huge because I need the stock combination(itself massive) and weights for each stock(even larger than the quadrillion combination).  To make matters more complicated, I'm taking daily data but am trying to build a long term model.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do(its impossible because of the size but just so it makes it more clear), I take all the possible portfolio that have a return of more than 3% today(lets pretend I need to study this on the portfolio as a whole and it cannot be derived from individual stocks). Then, I look at that portfolio and see if it did the same thing yesterday, day before that and so on..after going back X days, then I return the portfolio.

This way is not feasible because the entire population is huge(it would take a few billion years to process all combinations) and the results that work everyday are huge as well. If I'm trying to build portfolios how can I intelligently draw samples from this?  I've tried genetic algorithms to mutate successful ones but the problem is it may work but I might be in a local peak, so I tried to do random sampling as well but that didn't work very well.  I'm trying to think of ways of not sampling randomly. Any ideas?

(if its not clear here's another problem that is more general but also illustrates where I'm lost when it comes to sampling): say you wanted to know what percent of the entire world liked Democrats every year. The world is too large to poll everyone and its very diverse so doing it randomly may give you areas with high population(i.e. india/China but you'd miss out on smaller countries). Plus to complicate things, the answer this year will cause you to go back to look at the answer they gave last year and so on.  I'm interested in the sampling techniques, do you somehow segment the world into smaller groups and equally take samples(then a small country would have just as many votes as a large one? or do you do it randomly? etc..).

Thanks.

p.s. I know this is highly dependent on my research set but I'm trying to learn about general ideas so I can use existing methods as a model of thinking about this problem.  I'm have taken basic stats courses back in school but I'm not sure if this question is about sampling or if its about random sampling. Any suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: I didn't try to follow your original financial question but I do think I understand your voting analogy.  To make sure you hit all the countries you can stratify.  Take a stratified random sample preferably sampling proportional to size.  Smaller countries should have small weight because they have less total votes. In the end what are you estimating?  Proportion of Democratic votes?  If you can achieve proportion to size selection then your total democrat votes/ total votes is an unbiased estimate.

Comment: But if you could you would have to take a weighted average of the strata proportions to adjust for the bias.

Comment: @MichaelChernick Wow thanks..your answer is great but even more so, googling stratify gave me a list of other sampling techniques.  You understand the problem correctly but what if you didn't now the population of every country? You knew there was large/small pockets of people here and people are not spread eventually but you didn't know what those proportions were.  Is the approach the same still?

Comment: If you don't know the population sizes for the countries you wouldn't be able to sample proportional to size.  Sampling proportional to size gives you automatically an unbiased estimate of the average of the scores.  If you don't sample proportional to size you could adjust by taking a weighted average.  The problem is that not knowing the relative size for each stratum you wouldn't know how to weigh5t each stratum.

Comment: @MichaelChernick Thats my problem..I know the size of the overall population(7billion people in the entire world) but I don't know how they are dispersed so my ramdom sampling could randomly taking all the samples from the same subgroup. Maybe another way of putting it, say you wanted to sample everyone in your State and you had a phone book of everyone, you can't identify the regions they are in so how do you sample? Doing it randomly or even every 1000th person could localize the results, right?

Comment: Stratifying will help insure that you don't miss important subgroups but without information on relative sizes of the strata you can't know what weight you need to eliminate bias from your estiamte.

Comment: @MichaelChernick Thanks I get it. I'm going to dig deeper in different sampling methods and hopefully figure a way to figure out the weight of the subgroup.  Sorry dumb question, but if I can't figure out the relative sizes is there an impact in simply treating each group as equal weighted? To use my stock example, I know there are different groups(combos of stocks) but to find out the exact size of each would take too long. btw, thx for your help so far, you have really set me on the path I wanted.

Comment: THE IMPACT COMES IF THE MEANS BY STRATA GROUP DIFFER A LOT. THEN THE WEIGHTED AVERAGE WILL BE VERY DIFFERENT FROM THE STRAIGHT AVERAGE AND YOUR ESTIMATE COULD HAVE A LARGE BIAS. YOU WILL BE ABLE TO SEE WHEN YOU COMPUTE THE WITHIN STRATA MEANS IF THERE IS A PROBLEM BUT YOU WON'T KNOW WHAT WEIGHTS TO USE TO FIX IT.  YOU CAN VARY THE WEIGHTS TO SEE TH SENSITIVITY BUT YOU WON'T KNOW WHAT THE BEST ESTIMATE IS.

Comment: Are you mad, @MichaelChernick?

Comment: Thanks Micheal! Your a star! @Macro I don't think he's mad, just maybe very passionate about sampling(if you think about it, we all should be).

Comment: @Macro No anger intended. I thinkthe OP and I are getting along fine. My caplock was stuck and instead of erasing and retyping I thought the caps would be good for emphasis. Didn't mean to portray anger. I would edit it now if I could.

Comment: It was really more of a joke than anything :-) Also, I did laugh out loud at your comment, @Lostsoul

Comment: The question sounds like "random portfolios": you want to sample, not from the set of all portfolios, but from the set of portfolios satisfying some conditions (returns yesterday above 3%, returns two days ago above 3%, etc.). If rejection sampling does not work (if the proportion of portfolios satisfying the constraints is too small), you can take a portfolio at random (among all portfolios), and change it, as little as possible, so that it satisfies the constraints. But beware: the sampling is not uniform...

Comment: @VincentZoonekynd this was exactly my idea but there's a problem what I get a portfolio that satisfied my requirement above 3% and modify it to keep that return but what if there's a better one? I think using this approach I never get a chance to find ones that could do better...unless I'm understanding what your saying wrong.

Comment: If you do that repeatedly, with different starting portfolios, you will get many different portfolios. For instance, if you use an optimizer, you could minimize the distance between the porfolio to be returned and the starting portfolio, subject to your constraints. You end up with many portfolios, in the feasible region -- but they are not uniformly distributed: there are more of them on the boundary and the vertices than inside the feasible region.

Comment: @VincentZoonekynd First off, I'm very sorry if I misunderstand what your saying(I suck at stats), but say I have a portfolio of 3 stocks abc and I generate samples from it, won't I potentially miss xyz portfolio since it would be impossible for me to get that combination startin at abc? I'm sorry if I'm misunderstanding you(which I believe I am)

Comment: You are likely to miss it, but it is not sure (when modifying the starting portfolio to satisfy the constraints, the computer will try to add or remove stocks and may get closer to xyz). That is why you should repeat the procedure with many starting portfolios: 1. take a portfolio at random, say ABC, modify it to satisfy the constraints, and you have your first sample, A'B'C'; 2. Take another portfolio at random, say DEF, modify it to satisfy the constraints, and you have your second sample, D'E'F'; Repeat until you have enough samples.

Comment: @VincentZoonekynd I think we're on the same page(I think I understand what your saying)..my question basically instead of going completely random.so I could get abc,abd,adc,etc..is there anything I can do to get the most diverse set possible..

Comment: A few caveats and improvements are described in [this article](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1856476), but there is not much you can do.

Comment: @VincentZoonekynd ahh not the answer I was hoping for but you have been super helpful..Your in finance right? Is it more realistic to find a few good stocks and then randomly generate a portfolio around those? So your starting portfolio are changed as your few stocks change(or even a mixture of those stocks)?

Answer (score 1):

I think I can give you a better answer now.  There is a method called random allocation.  You can use unequal selection probabilities in your design.  This means that for groups that are undersampled you can increase there probability of selection as the data are being collected.  I think you could combine the two ideas by having fixed strata and then apply random allocation within each stratum.  You can find more details on this using the key words and phrases "random allocation", "group sequential designs" and "adaptive designs".

Also because you have unknown population sizes even though you won't know the population sizes of each country you could do a capture-recapture design to estiamte the size of the unknown population.  Look up terms using Google such as "estimating the size of a population" and "capture-recapture" methods.  This involves tagging samples and giving thema chance to be sampled on a second draw.  Fisheries use this quite a lot to determine the abundance of fish populations in rivers or oceans.